# WIX Custom install dir

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I've seen this question asked many different times, and I've tried nearly everything to create a user configurable install dir...

I'm using local app data folder and default to a per-user installtion which I suspect may be causing my issue.

Here's some code:

Directory creation:

```
<Property Id="INSTALLLOCATION"
              Value="INSTALLDIR" />

    <!--Directory structure-->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
               Name="SourceDir">
      <!--Move directory creation to custom action-->
      <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR"
                   Name="My app">
```

Dialogs

```
 <UI Id="WixUI_Minimal">
  ....
  ....
  <Property Id="WixUI_Mode"
            Value="Minimal" />

  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExitDialog"/>
  <DialogRef Id="SuccessDialog"/>
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDialog"/>

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDialog"
           Control="Next"
           Event="NewDialog"
           Value="PrepareDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDialog"
          Control="Options"
          Event="NewDialog"
          Value="MyInstallDirDlg">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MyInstallDirDlg" 
           Control="Next" 
           Event="SetTargetPath"
           Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" 
           Order="1">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyInstallDirDlg"
           Control="Next"
           Event="DoAction"
           Value="WixUIValidatePath" 
           Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyInstallDirDlg"
           Control="Next" 
           Event="SpawnDialog" 
           Value="InvalidDirDlg"
           Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyInstallDirDlg" 
           Control="Next"
           Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="VerifyReadyDlg" 
           Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyInstallDirDlg"
           Control="ChangeFolder"
           Property="_BrowseProperty"
           Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]"
           Order="1">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyInstallDirDlg"
           Control="ChangeFolder" 
           Event="SpawnDialog"
           Value="BrowseDlg"
           Order="2">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="ConfigOptionsDialog"
           Control="Next"
           Event="NewDialog"
           Value="PrepareDlg">1</Publish>
   ....
   ....
```

Reference to install dir

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR"/>
```

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: Errors when I navigate to the dialog. Was getting error 2343, after some changes, getting error 2812.